# OpenGL version and color depth

Tags: opengl

I made a program, that changes resolution, color depth,... and then it render simple texture on screen. It all works without any problem until I switch to 8b color depth. Then there appears problem of calling non-existing functions (function points to 0x00) like glCreateShader. It made me wonder and I got idea, which proved to be correct. Created context have really low version.

After calling glGetString(GL_VERSION) i recieved that context version was 1.1.0. With higher color depths it returns 4.4

Is there any reason for decreasing version? I looked through google and some of opengl.org pages, but I did not found anything about deprecating 8b color depth. Even Windows CAN switch to this color depth so there is no reason why OpenGL shouldn't be able to handle this.

Sure i can emulate it by decreasing number of colors, memory is not what I am concerned. I just want to know why is this happening. Program is prototype for lab experiments, so i need to have as many options as possible and this is just cutting one third away.

Last thing i should add is that program is written in C/C++ with Winapi and some WGL functions, but I think that this does not matter much.

Comment: Are you explicitly requesting a specific version of the context? If not, then afaik the driver can give you whatever version it wants.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes, I tried it, but with same result. Still after screen switch to 8b color depth, OpenGL version decreases to 1.1.0

Comment: I suspect that the graphics card driver doesn't support 8bpp surfaces in hardware, so it drops you down to a less-supported software-emulated version of OpenGL. Having a shader that fake-reduces the color-depth is probably a better option anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your graphics driver is falling back to the software implementation because no hardware accelerated pixel format matching your criteria could be found.

Most drivers will not give you hardware accelerated 8-bit per-pixel formats, *especially* if you request an RGB[*A*] (`WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB`) color mode.

> Sure i can emulate it by decreasing number of colors, memory is not what I am concerned. I just want to know why is this happening.

To get an 8-bit format, you must use an indexed color mode (`WGL_TYPE_COLORINDEX_ARB`); paletted rendering. I suspect modern drivers will not even support that sort of thing unless they offer a compatibility profile (which rules out platforms like OS X).

The smallest RGB color depth you should realistically attempt is RGB555 or RGB565. 15/16-bit color is supported on modern hardware. Indexed color modes, on the other hand, are really pushing your luck.